# ODRefreshController for UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

In my iPhone application, I am using a Web view to show user feeds. For refreshing, I am sending the server request while the user scrolls up from the top. I would like to use some cool kind of refreshing for this.

I have tried `ODRefresh` controller (Git-[here](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl)), but it is only working with Scroll view and Table view, not with `UIWebVIew` (and App crashes). I have implemented the `UIScrollView` delegate to webview using `addScrollViewListener` method, but I'm still having no luck.

My code is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ODRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[ODRefreshControl alloc] initInScrollView:self.myWebView];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(dropViewDidBeginRefreshing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)dropViewDidBeginRefreshing:(ODRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
    double delayInSeconds = 3.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });
}

- (void) addScrollViewListener
{
    UIScrollView* currentScrollView;
    for (UIView* subView in myWebView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            currentScrollView = (UIScrollView*)subView;
            currentScrollView.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ODRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[ODRefreshControl alloc] initInScrollView:[[self.myWebView subviews] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Or

```
ODRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[ODRefreshControl alloc] initInScrollView:[[self.myWebView subviews]lastObject]];
```

Comment: Or indeed, `webView.scrollView`? Why not just use the property? (iOS5 and later)

Comment: if there is any problem in when i upload it in Appstore

Comment: Apple will not reject it . I got an App that uses the same class live and kicking in the AppStore .